# Haskell Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Char, b0)]’ with actual type ‘(Char, Int)’

Tags: haskell

So I have got this piece of code, which returns an error on it's expected type. 
Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Char, b0)]’
with actual type ‘(Char, Int)’
In the expression: newList
In a stmt of a list comprehension: (a, b) <- newList

I want to get the location of the character back, so that would be 'b'. I just don't understand why it gives me a type error. Whenever I run the code one by one inside the WinGHCI, I'll get the correct information back. When putting it in a .hs file, it won't.

```
word = "apple"
isPart :: Char -> a
isPart x = do
            newList <- zip word [0..length word]
            result <- [b | (a,b) <- newList, a == x]
            return result
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `do` block

```
newList <- zip word [0..length word]
```

is desugared into something like

```
zip word [0..length] >>= \newList -> ...
```

The type of `>>=` is `(Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

Since `zip` returns a list, you are using the list monad and therefore the type of `newList` is actually an `(Int, Char)`. You cannot then use that as the source for the subsequent list comprehension.

However you don't need to use `do` at all:

```
isPart :: Char -> Int
isPart x = let newList = zip word [0..length word]
               result = [b | (a,b) <- newList, a == x]
           in  head result
```

although be aware this will throw an error if the given character is not in `word`

You can also write this more simply as

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

isPart x = fromJust $ elemIndex x word
```

although a better solution would be to change the return type to `Maybe Int` instead of using `fromJust`.